# Problem writing to file fs module, apparently the path is positioned at the root level

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, fs

I'm practicing with **typescript** and I want to write a file using fs module but I don't know if is this a noob question or I'm doing something wrong but my project look like this:

> root
>
> **-> dir** (here are the js result from tsc)
>
> **-> src**
>
> --> data
>
> ---> data.json
>
> --> service
>
> ---> service.ts
>
> --> index.ts
>
> **-> package.json**
>
> **-> tsconfig.json**

And at service.ts apparently the path is:
`let filePath = path.join('./','src','data','data.json') // this works`

`fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(data,null,2), 'utf8', (err)=>{ if(err){ return console.log(err);}})`

So I don't know why the path is positioned at the root level

If I try "../data/data.json" I get ENOENT ERROR no such file or directory

Is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filesystem operations with relative paths always use the Current Working Directory - a concept explained here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

When you run Node.js, you do so while being in a particular directory. For example, scripts such as `npm start` are usually executed in the root-level directory of a repository/project - this causes all relative paths to resolve starting from there. Note, however, that this may be different in production - it is possible for Docker, PM2, systemd, or any other tool to run your script while being in a different working directory (this can often be configured).

To inspect your current working directory in Node.js, use https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processcwd

It is also possible to build paths relative to the directory of the JS file. This tutorial shows various examples on how to do that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-how-to-use__dirname

It is important to remember that `require()` uses paths relative to __dirname, but `fs` resolves relative to CWD.